# Can't show XML file with asp.net ListView or Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, repeater

I am trying to show the following XML file on my asp.NET page, but it just won't work.

```
<Calendar>
  <Info>
    <CalendarID>95</CalendarID>
    <CalendarName>
      <![CDATA[ Kalender Jebjerg ]]>
    </CalendarName>
    <AppointmentInterval>1 days</AppointmentInterval>
    <RefreshInterval>5 minutes</RefreshInterval>
    <FreeAccessUntil>2013-01-15 09:12:27</FreeAccessUntil>
    <NextExportAvailable>2013-09-11 17:58:56</NextExportAvailable>
  </Info>
  <Appointment>
    <Ressource>
      <![CDATA[ Hallen ]]>
    </Ressource>
    <StartDate>2013-09-11 15:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2013-09-11 18:00:00</EndDate>
    <Subject>
      <![CDATA[ KIG - Gymnastik ]]>
    </Subject>
    <Description>
      <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </Description>
  </Appointment>
  <Appointment>
    <Ressource>
     <![CDATA[ KIG ]]>
    </Ressource>
    <StartDate>2013-09-11 15:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2013-09-11 19:00:00</EndDate>
    <Subject>
      <![CDATA[ KIG - Gymnastik ]]>
    </Subject>
    <Description>
      <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </Description>
  </Appointment>
</Calendar>
```

I already tested my .aspx page with dummy XML file and it worked fine!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <h3><%#XPath("Subject") %></h3>
    <p>Start: <%#XPath("StartDate") %>. End: <%#XPath("EndDate") %></p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://server.liveconnect.dk/xml/calendar/?cid=95&xid=e96de1864025d98d22b86537d02bb93e"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

It won't show the data. My concern is that the Info-element in the XML mess up the repeater.

Comment: Please don't link to pertinent code in your question. Include it here.

Comment: what are Subject, StartDate and EndDate? I dont seem them in your XML file.

Comment: I just updated it. Zach Smith only took the 'Info' element, but the rest af the XML contains 'Appointment' elements.

Comment: @user1594814 have you tried "#XPath("Calender/Appointment/Subject")"?

Comment: Yes I already tried that - still not working :(

Comment: @MartinMojito Oh, my mistake. I apologize for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.xpath.aspx) selector on your XmlDataSource:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource XPath="Calendar/Appointment" ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://server.liveconnect.dk/xml/calendar/?cid=95&xid=e96de1864025d98d22b86537d02bb93e"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

to get the correct children. Since you have different children under the root Calendar, XmlDataSource thinks it should use the first one (Info), while you want to use the others.

Comment: Hi again Samu Lang, can you help me once again ? I would like to filter my xml by Ressource, but still be able to access its siblings (StartDate etc.). I have been playing around with XPath(Calendar/Appointment/Ressource[text() = "Hallen"], but then I can not retrieve data from all the child notes af Appointment. Any help ?

Comment: Again, you have to include this filtering in your XPath attribute on the data-source itself. Use [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains): `<asp:XmlDataSource XPath="Calendar/Appointment[contains(Ressource, 'Hallen')]" runat="server" >`.

Comment: Thanks alot once again !

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This answer is incorrect due to additional information provided in comments.** [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746459/359704) is correct.

Your XML file doesn't include the elements you're trying to display.

Here's what I see from [your XML](http://server.liveconnect.dk/xml/calendar/?cid=95&xid=e96de1864025d98d22b86537d02bb93e):

```
<Calendar>
  <Info>
    <CalendarID>95</CalendarID>
    <CalendarName><![CDATA[Kalender Jebjerg]]></CalendarName>
    <AppointmentInterval>1 days</AppointmentInterval>
    <RefreshInterval>5 minutes</RefreshInterval>
    <FreeAccessUntil>2013-01-15 09:12:27</FreeAccessUntil>
    <NextExportAvailable>2013-09-11 18:04:41</NextExportAvailable>
  </Info>
</Calendar>
```

There's no `Subject`, `StartDate` or `EndDate` elements under `Info`.

If, for example, you modify your code to show some elements that **are** in the XML, you'll see that the repeater is working fine:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%#XPath("CalendarID") %></h2>
        <h3><%#XPath("Subject")%></h3>
        <p>Start: <%#XPath("StartDate")%>. End: <%#XPath("EndDate")%></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://server.liveconnect.dk/xml/calendar/?cid=95&xid=e96de1864025d98d22b86537d02bb93e"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Comment: See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745918/cant-show-xml-file-with-asp-net-listview-or-repeater/18746459#18746459).

Comment: BTW your XML keeps reverting back to the original.